# Ajax : Get rid of unwanted text with data

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to get the new data from controller every 10 seconds. but the ajax return unwanted text that comes with the data. Is there anyway to get rid of the text that comes with data? I'm sorry about my English

Here the result that showing on the page

[image: View]

i only want the number "1077" and "7"

This is my controller

```
ajax: function(req, res){
    knex.raw("CALL GetQueuePlay('00');")
     .then(function(result){
        var number = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result[0][0]));
        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result[0][0])))
        return res.send({q_play_list:number});
      }) 
},
```

and this is Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ajax",
        data: { QNum: 0 , station_num: 0 },
        success: function(data){
            $('#kue1').text(JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log('Data Appeared!' + data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("something is wrong: ", error);
        }

    });
},10000)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see q_play_list is an array. On receiving the response, you can loop through the array and read the properties QNum and station_num, store it in variable and then display it in the UI. Like so:

```
    if(data["q_play_list"] && Array.isArray(["q_play_list"])){
         var playList = data["q_play_list"];
         var playListLength = data["q_play_list"].length;
         for(var i = 0; i< playListLength; i++){
           var textToBeDisplayed = playList[i].QNum || "";
           textToBeDisplayed + = playList[i].station_num? " "+playList[i].station_num : "";
           $('#kue1').text(textToBeDisplayed );
         }
    }
```

Comment: this is also work! I'm quite new to the JS. May i ask what does the "?" behind station_num stand for?

Comment: "?" is a conditional operator. More on this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp

Comment: Thanks, man. I don't even know before these things are exist in JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
Object.values(q_play_list[0])
```

Or, you can use regex to filter out the non digit characters if that ever happens.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: it works! Thank you. But may i have further question? Why the Object.values can do the trick but not JSON?

Comment: JSON.stringify(obj) just puts all the properties between quotes as far as I know, and JSON.parse does the opposite, so you're not really "selecting" anything, just changing the object that's already there